# Creating input element continuing ID enumeration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that creates 4 input elements inside a DIV after click:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<button class="check">Check</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var num = 4;
    $(".check").click(function(){
        for(i=0; i<num;i++){
            $("#content").append("<input id='input"+i+"' type='text'><br>");
        }
    });
</script>
```

But the problem is I want input id number continues the enumeration (like this example) instead of return to zero:

```
<div id="content">
<input id="input0" type="text">
<input id="input1" type="text">
<input id="input2" type="text">
<input id="input3" type="text">
<input id="input4" type="text">
<input id="input5" type="text">
<input id="input6" type="text">
<input id="input7" type="text">
...and continues
</div>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: why not set a variable outside of the scope of your function that keeps track of your current number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `id` of the last `input`. Here I am calculating start and end of for loop based on the total number of elements in `#container`.

```js
var num = 4;
$(".check").click(function() {

  var start = $("#content input").length;
  var end = start + num;

  for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
    var id = 'input' + i;
    $("#content").append("<input id='"+id+"' type='text' value='"+id+"'><br>");
    
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
<button class="check">Check</button>
```

PS: Here input value is just to demonstrate the id setting to input.

Comment: thanks for the answer, now how could I modify it if var num is changed value dynamically?

Comment: @NekoLopez how are you changing var num?

Answer (score 2):

You need some kind of global variable here, or use that simple one:

```
var getID = (function () {
  var id = 0;
  return function () { return ++id; }
})();
```

So whenever you call `getID()` the »internal« id will be incremented, so each call will yield an new ID.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".check").click(function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    $('<input type="text">')                            //create a new input
      .attr('id', 'input' + $('#content input').length) //id based on number of inputs
      .appendTo('#content');                            //append it to the container
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
<button class="check">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to have a stack of elements to *begin* with, and then continue enumeration from there, you simply need to set a variable to the ID of the latest element.

All you need to do is count the number of elements. This can be done with a combination of **[`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)** and **[`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)**.

Then simply have your loop **start** at this new value instead of `0`.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
var total_desired = 20;
var start = document.querySelectorAll('#content > input').length;

console.log(start + " elements to start with");

$(".check").click(function() {
  for (i = start; i < total_desired; i++) {
    $("#content").append("<input id='input" + i + "' type='text'><br>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="check">Check</button>

<div id="content">
  <input id="input0" type="text">
  <input id="input1" type="text">
  <input id="input2" type="text">
  <input id="input3" type="text">
  <input id="input4" type="text">
  <input id="input5" type="text">
  <input id="input6" type="text">
  <input id="input7" type="text"> ...and continues
</div>
```

Having said that, it's unlikely that you actually *need* simultaneous ID `<input>` elements, and you may benefit from *classes* instead.

Answer (score 0):

**You can create this object:**

```
var MyId = {
  a: 0,
  toString() {
    return this.a++;
  }
}
```

And concatenate it into the string.  Automatically will increase the counter.

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<button class="check">Check</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var GetID = {
      a: 0,
      toString() {
        return this.a++;
      }
    }
    
    var num = 4;
    $(".check").click(function(){
        for(i=0; i<num;i++){
            $("#content").append("<input id='input"+GetID+"' type='text'><br>");
        }
    });
</script>
```